# Renaming column in Python SQL table

Tags: python, pandas

I am appending data to a dataframe using the pandas library and am renaming my columns in the code below:

```
chunksize = 20000
j = 0
index_start = 1

for df in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/jjj.tsv', chunksize=chunksize, header = None,sep='\t', iterator=True, encoding='utf-8'):
    df=df.rename(columns = {0:'screen',1:'user'})
    df.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
    index_start = df.index[-1] + 1
    j=j+1
    if j >=2:
        break
    else:
        count = j*chunksize
        print(count)
        print(j)
```

However, when I execute a simple query:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 3', disk_engine)
```

I get:

```
    index   0   1
0   0   293 3785616
1   1   3250207 5540538
2   2   1000052 5542982
```

Why are my columns not renamed? Should have  `df=df.rename(columns = {0:'screen',1:'user'})`renamed the columns?

Comment: what is the output of `df.columns.tolist()` after renaming the columns?

Comment: I see ['screen', 'user']. For some reason I am not seeing that in the output I get from the query. When I run df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE screen = 293 LIMIT 3', disk_engine) I get an error saying screen is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rename your columns on the fly while reading CSV by specifying the `names` parameter:

```
pd.read_csv('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/jjj.tsv',
            chunksize=chunksize,
            header = None,
            sep='\t',
            iterator=True,
            encoding='utf-8',
            names=['screen','user'])
```

PS most probably you've created your SQL table first time, not renaming your columns - try to drop and recreate it

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rename columns, the best strategy is to use the inplace flag,

```
df.rename(columns = {0:'screen',1:'user'}, inplace=True)
```